# Passing $http data from service to controller (async)

Tags: angularjs, api, asynchronous

I'm learning Angular by making a weather app. So, In index.html I have a dropdown list.

```
<select ng-model="city" ng-options="city.cityName for city in cities" ng-change="getWheather()">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Depending on what city user selects from that list, he gets a weather forecast. It was all working perfectly while the function `getWheather()` was in the controller. Once I've put it in a factory, it is not longer working. I assume its because it is asynchronous, but I have no luck in fixing it.

This is the factory (in URL, numbers 45 and 15 should be `city.latit` and `city.longit`, but I can't get it to work. If I pass the value "city" to function getWheather(), it is undefined):

```
app.factory('wheatherService', function($http) {
  var getWheather = function(){
    var url ="https://api.forecast.io/forecast/api_key/"+45.815+","+15.966+"?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
      return $http.jsonp(url);
  };

  return {
    getWheather: getWheather
  };
});
```

This is the controller:

```
app.controller('inputCtrl', function($scope, wheatherService){
  $scope.cities = [{ "cityName" : 'Paris', "latit" : 45.815399, "longit" : 15.966568},
                   { "cityName" : 'London', "latit" : 45.328979, "longit" : 14.457664},
                   { "cityName" : 'NewYork', "latit" : 43.510742, "longit" : 16.437489 }];

  wheatherService.getWheather().success(function(data){
    $scope.wheatherData = data;
      console.log($scope.wheatherData);
  });
});
```

So the main question is - is there and what is the way to get selected value from dropdown list to getWheather() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still not bind **Controller** `getWheather` method to any function for later use in view.

```
$scope.getWheather = getWheather;
```

Then you call the promise on getWheather method

```
function getWheather(city){
    wheatherService.getWheather(city).success(function(data){
        $scope.wheatherData = data;
        console.log($scope.wheatherData);
  });
}
```

In you view `ng-change` should pass city as parameter

```
ng-change="getWheather(city)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `city` object to function.

```
ng-change="getWheather(city)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in the view you should call the functions from the controller and the controller should be the one communicating with the factory.

But, to try answering your question, if you pass city to getWheather it will be undifined since you are not accepting any parameters inside your getWheather function.

`var getWheather = function(){...` should be `var getWheather = function(city){...`

and then in the factory you should try something like this.

`var url ="https://api.forecast.io/forecast/api_key/"+ city.latit +","+ city.longit +"?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";`

Hope this works for you =D!